# setting the base for log scale in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to d3, and just getting the hang of it. My requirement is pretty simple. I want the x-axis to be log scaled to a base of some decimal number. The default log scale has a base of 10. And scouring the reference API and the web hasnt yielded me a way of changing the base. Might be i'm missing something basic about d3. But i cant seem to get past this obstacle. Ideally, shouldnt there be a log.base() similar to the pow.exponent() for the power scale

Comment: See the answer & comments of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247305/d3-js-non-linear-graph-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such a function (although it wouldn't be too hard to add one). Your best bet is to write your own function that does the necessary log transformation you specify and then passes the result on to a normal linear scale to get the final value.

Comment: Seems like this function is now available https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#log-scales

Answer (score 3):

d3.scale.log().base(2) seems to work fine. (As Adrien Be points out.)

Comment: `.base()` doesn't seem to work as intended, see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289719/d3-log-scale-base-not-making-an-effect)