# d3.js : non linear graph axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add a custom scale on an axis, such as below

[image: my custom scale]

The idea is that a tick is always 2 times bigger than a previous tick.

My understanding is that this is a custom scale. I did a bit of research & could not find anything like it.

So I guess my question is actually two questions:

1. Is this scale "standard" in the mathematical world?
2. Is this possible to implement this using `d3.js` ?

Any link to related tutorial or live example (ie. jsFiddle) is also welcome.

EDIT: I have now asked [a related question on mathematica.stackexchange.com to help me find the solution to this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51823/chart-with-its-ticks-in-geometric-progression) & will update this post after I have tried a few things.

Comment: Have you considered using logarithmic scales instead?

Comment: Yes, I actually had the same idea at first. I did get it to work with my log scale (default base, so base 10). But this is not "good enough"...

Comment: Been trying but can't get this to work. Could you modify the scale on the Y axis on this example http://jsbin.com/isuris/484/ to show how I could similarly use `ordinal`?

Comment: My initial suggestion was bad. I'll try to look into it later this evening, but I think it's definitely possible.

Comment: Alright, thx. I'll keep investigating on my side & will update this post if I find a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Polylinear scales can be used in this scenario. From [linear scale api documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_domain):

> Although linear scales typically have just two numeric values in their
>   domain, you can specify more than two values for a polylinear scale.
>   In this case, there must be an equivalent number of values in the
>   output range. A polylinear scale represents multiple piecewise linear
>   scales that divide a continuous domain and range.

Here's an example that fits your requirements:

```
// Your custom scale:
var customScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([125,250,500,1000,2000])
        .range([0,50,100,150,200]);

// The axis uses the above scale and the same domain:
var axis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(customScale)
        .tickValues([125,250,500,1000,2000]);
```

Knowing the number of ticks as well as the extents of domain and range, the computation of both arrays is trivial (note that they must be of equal length).

Comment: thx Oleg, I'll try this & let you know how it goes. Bonne journée

Comment: Thanks Oleg, this worked like a charm. See how I turned this graph http://jsbin.com/isuris/484/ Y-axis into a polynear scale (here a log 125 scale) http://jsbin.com/isuris/537/

Comment: I'd still use logarithmic scales in this case https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#log-scales, but hey, I'm happy you're happy :)

Comment: ohoh, I did miss this info. And I came across that question that mentioned log scale not being available (at the time it was asked) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871769/setting-the-base-for-log-scale-in-d3-js I'd still accept your answer as this is still a valid "working" solution, and I only "assumed" my scale is log base 125, I have not actually verified it.