# d3 log scale: base not making an effect?

Tags: d3.js

I feel like this may be simply me misunderstanding how logarithmic scales work, but I can't seem to get D3 log scale bases to work.

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esm4kLwg/3/), I attempt to create three scales with the same set of base10 ticks, with a base10 log scale, a base4 log scale, and a base2 log scale. According to my layperson understanding of logarithmic scales, the base10 log scale looks correct — the powers of ten are equidistantly spaced on the axis. But, the base4 and base2 scales are identical — it seems to me that the labels should compress to the right on those two scales. What's going on?

Fiddly code:

```
ticks = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000]
elems = { ten: 10, four: 4, two: 2 }

for selector, base of elems
  dom = d3.select('.scale.' + selector)
  scale = (new d3.scale.log()).base(base).domain([ 0.5, 10000000 ]).range([ 0, 500 ])

  dom.selectAll('div')
    .data(ticks)
    .enter().append('div')
      .text((x) -> x)
      .style('left', (x) -> scale(x) + 'px')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The base() method is a bit of a misnomer, IMO. It is actually a *displayBase* method, in that it only updates the positioning and label of the ticks.

Scales use the *domain* and *range* settings to do their magic. This is a nicely consistent way of doing things across many different scales, but with logs it is a little unintuitive.

**The awkward way**: In your case, modify the upper value of the domain array. For example, if the range is [0, 1000], then the domain should be [1, 3] for log-base10, and [0, 9.9658 (approx)] for log-base2. In general, top domain value is the log(base-x) of the top range value. Ditto with the bottom range value if it is higher than 0.

**The simpler way**: Leave the range as [0,1]. Then you can set the domain as [1, base]. The scale takes care of interpolation outside the range values.

Comment: Only just saw that I got an answer here. Thanks for the response! We ended up just using an ordinal scale since our intervals are well-defined; much easier to control what's going on that way. This looks like a good approach to try next time though!